# Replacing modulus with multiplication

Tags: math, optimization, modulus, integer-arithmetic

I would like to compute `x % y` (i.e. `x mod y`), where `x`, `y` are unsigned 64-bit integers and `y` is a constant.

Is it true that it is possible to replace the modulus operation with some combination of multiplication, addition, shift and some well chosen constants?

How to derive such sequence of arithmentic operations and constants?

If it is not possible in general case of `x` and `y`, would it work for some reasonable subset of inputs, say if `y` was odd?

Comment: `x % y` is defined to be `x - (x / y) * y`, so if you can implement integer division with the above operations (e.g. using multiplication with binary search), the rest follows. EDIT: just found [this](https://gist.github.com/ichenq/4243253) algorithm which uses only subtract and shift, but not sure how fast it is on fixed-size types compared to multiplication.